# redis cluster set and get not happening with all the nodes

Tags: redis

I am new to redis.

I have multiple instance of redis running. When I am trying to set key I am getting error as "MOVED xxxx IP:port.

I should able to do set and get using any node from the cluster. Can someone help me what I am I missing.

```
root@redis-0:/# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379>
127.0.0.1:6379> set name1 Rock
(error) MOVED 12933 10.60.3.54:6379
127.0.0.1:6379>
127.0.0.1:6379>
root@redis-0:/#
root@redis-0:/# exit


root@redis-1:/#
root@redis-1:/# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379>
127.0.0.1:6379>
127.0.0.1:6379> get name1
"deba"
127.0.0.1:6379>
127.0.0.1:6379> set name2 Tom
(error) MOVED 742 10.60.3.55:6379
127.0.0.1:6379>

127.0.0.1:6379> CLUSTER NODES
cbe713bf93c67adceed0d79e5b2d6a5a40b31625 10.60.3.53:6379@16379 master - 0 1533054504070 2 connected 5461-10922
2a65bcc6355cecb58df8d99dbee4da1fe4b5af70 10.60.3.55:6379@16379 master - 0 1533054502065 1 connected 0-5460
e7b5ff6bbb90cba775b1128f88de70c116ef18f6 10.60.3.54:6379@16379 myself,master - 0 1533054501000 3 connected 10923-16383
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should able to do set and get using any node from the cluster.

Yes and no. As @ItamarHaber already stated, you can do this only on right node.

But if you want to go the right node *automatically* while using redis-cli, you can use `-c` switch.

So, instead of

```
# redis-cli
```

try

```
# redis-cli -c
```

Answer (score 2):

> I should able to do set and get using any node from the cluster.

You are able to do that, but you have to go to the right node to set a given key.

I suggest that you use a Redis Cluster-aware client and/or read about how the cluster works, and specifically how data is sharded, at https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial